# Complexity of specific function

Tags: c, complexity-theory

So I need to analyze the complexity of this function and express it as a function of "x" and "epsilon". I tried to express it through a log with base epsiolon and x as parameter but to no avail.

```
double exhaustiveSquareRoot(double x, double epsilon)
{
    double result, step;
    step = epsilon * epsilon;
    result = 0.0;

    while (abs(result*result - x) > epsilon && result < x)
        result += result+step;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You could always gather data. Hold epsilon fixed and try with various x -- plotting passes through the loop as a function of x. Then hold x fixed and let epsilon vary, plotting the results. Do the plots look linear? Quadratic? Logarithmic? None of this proves anything, but is a good way to gain intuition and can suggest the answer.